# Axis2 system cannot infer the transport information error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I'm trying to send a SOAP request using client code that uses libraries generated by wsdl2java tool for eclipse, but keep on getting this error:

```
[ERROR] The system cannot infer the transport information from the Address: http://172.17.4.2:8081/axis2/services/CDMS URL.
```

This client is sort of a proxy that sits between a "real" client and a server. I obtained the URL from wsa:To field of the SOAP message from the real client, and use it to create a connection to the server.

I'm pretty lost as to looking for possible source of mistake, could anyone give a hint? I'm not sure which information I can give here that may be of use, so just let me know as for which other error messages or config file extracts that I should provide to help you helping me :)

Thanks...

**UPDATE:**

I made some more trials, the request was successfully sent if I hardcode the URL string to the client stub, instead of obtaining it from another message:

```
ConfigurationContext cc = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("/home/me/axis2-1.6.2/repository", "/home/me/axis2-1.6.2/conf/axis2.xml");
CDMSStub stub = new CDMSStub(cc, "http://172.17.4.2:8081/axis2/services/CDMS");
```

I don't understand why, because the string that I supplied has the exact same value/content as the hardcoded one....

Answer (score 3):

The error itself says that the it cannot resolve the endpoint for sending the message out. You need to make sure that your backend service is up and running. Also make sure your proxy service correctly configured to send the message to the backend service. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help but I was fighting this error for days.  Had a coworker help me and she explained that when I created the java classes from the wsdl file that the default (using RAD 7.5) was to use JAXB-WS.  For a stand alone application she suggested I use Axis.  Rebuilt all the java classes, fixed some parameters, and life it good.